# Using kendo.saveAs to download an excel or csv file from an action method

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid.  I'm using a jquery AJAX call to send data from the Grid to an Action method for processing.  Ok fine,  no problem there.  So after the processing of the data i now want to down either an excel file or csv file (which are basically the same thing).  But Jquerys AJAX method doesn't allow Action method to return files like (an excel file).  I had figured out another way to do this using 
window.location.href = "Controller/Actionmethod/MethodName?" + parameters
But this was a no go as my boss wants it all in one Action Method,  not two..

So now introduce this into the success call back of my AJAX call:

```
kendo.saveAs({
     dataURI: data.file,
     fileName: "PayrollExport.csv"
});
```

And here is my code for building the csv file which works fine.

```
                var export = Fundraisers.ProcessPledgeCardUltiproExport().Where(t => FundraiserIDs.Contains(t.FundraiserID)).ToList();

                var csv = new StringBuilder();
                csv.AppendLine(String.Format("Employee Number, Deduction code, Benefit Status, Coverage Start, Deduction Start Date, Employee Amount"));

                foreach (var e in export)
                {
                    var newLine = String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4:d},{5}", e.EmployeeID, "UW", "A", "", new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year + 1, 1, 1), e.PledgeAmount);
                    csv.AppendLine(newLine);
                }

                var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(csv.ToString());
                var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
```

Now my question is:     How do i return this from the action method.?
All i have as of right now is return Json(new { success = true, file = stream });

An example of what i would need that works for a PDF file is something along the line of:

```
return Json(new { success = true, message = "Verified!", file = "data:text/html;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(fileContent) });
```

Any idea on the what i should put in the return for the posted above code after creating the csv file?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: so you are trying to return the actual file?

Comment: Yes.  From the Action method

Comment: Did you try using httpfilebase to pass in the file to begin with, or do a request? Then you could retrieve it once it is modified